# Specify nodejs version in package.json file to make sure not use deprecated API

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I use `Buffer.from()` instead of the deprecated `new Buffer()` constructor in my project and want to specify node version in package.json.

As far as I know, `Buffer.from()` is not introduced in lower minor version of some major version of node.js. For example, `v5.1.0` does not support `Buffer.from` but `v5.10.0` does.

My question is:
I want to specify the node version from major version v4, but it would not be correct to specify like `>= 4.5.0`.

So, how to specify node version from v4 and make sure support `Buffer.from()`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`engine`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) option in `package.json`:

`"engines" : { "node" : ">=4.5.0 <5 || >=5.10.0 <6" }`